# visual studio 2008 on windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, windows-7

I have two separate machines. On first machine I have installed windows Xp and visual studio 2008 and on the other machine Windows 7 and visual studio 2008.
I have an application which was created on the first machine i.e. on windows Xp and visual studio 2008. 
Question: When I am trying to compile on windows 7 platform, it does not work. 
It shows errors for header file, resource file and linker errors.

P.S. - I saw nearly 350 header files on first machine under visual studio 2008 ....\vc\include
and on second machine only 150.
why this is so?

Comment: Looks like an installation/configuration problem to me. Seems you use C++. Don't you have to execute some batch files to extract/configure some library/header files?

Comment: Maybe show a sample of the errors.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have different versions of the Platform SDK on the two machines (although it's hard to be sure as you didn't say what the errors actually were).

Download and install the latest Windows Platform SDK via one of these methods:

- [Web Setup Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6b6c21d2-2006-4afa-9702-529fa782d63b&displaylang=en) (small initial download; downloads what it needs during installation)
- [.ISO DVD image](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35aeda01-421d-4ba5-b44b-543dc8c33a20&displaylang=en) (large, complete download)

(You might want to install it on both machines to keep them consistent.)

Ensure Visual Studio is not running when you install it, just in case.

After installing it, and with VS still not running, run the **Windows SDK Configuration Tool** which will now be in your start menu and ensure that VS2008 is configured to use the SDK you just installed.

Comment: VS2008 already includes the SDK, version 6.0a.  Installing another one is a good way to cause more trouble, the SDK installer is pretty crappy.

Comment: Using the configuration tool usually solves any trouble caused by installing an SDK, and ensuring both machines use the same SDK seems like a good idea. You can't sit on the SDK version that came with VS forever, either, unless you don't care about supporting new OS features.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try compiling it as "Any CPU" or "x86" ?
Incase if you still find issues try this 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx